# Compare 2 consecutive rows and check if date difference is within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have dataframe df:

```
    A   B   SortedDate  Selected
0   aa  200 01-Jan-20   Y
1   aa  200 23-Dec-19   Y
2   aa  200 12-Jun-19   N
3   bb  400 13-Mar-20   Y
4   bb  400 02-Feb-20   Y
5   bb  500 15-Mar-20   N
6   cc  700 02-Feb-20   Y
7   cc  700 02-Feb-20   Y
8   cc  900 03-Feb-20   N
9   dd  900 30-Jan-20   N
10  dd  200 30-Jan-20   N
```

I want to get the column 'Selected'=Y if for consecutive rows A and B is the same and SortedDate is within 2 months. 
I have tried [Compare 2 consecutive rows and assign increasing value if different (using Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979760/compare-2-consecutive-rows-and-assign-increasing-value-if-different-using-panda)
However, the answer is addressing different issues.

Can I have a suggestion for a clean way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print (df)
     A    B SortedDate Selected
0   aa  200  01-Jan-20        Y
1   aa  200  23-Dec-19        Y
2   aa  200  24-Oct-19        Y <- changed datetime
3   bb  400  13-Mar-20        Y
4   bb  400  02-Feb-20        Y
5   bb  500  15-Mar-20        N
6   cc  700  02-Feb-20        Y
7   cc  700  02-Feb-20        Y
8   cc  900  03-Feb-20        N
9   dd  900  30-Jan-20        N
10  dd  200  30-Jan-20        N
```

---

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['SortedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SortedDate'], format='%d-%b-%y')

#get shifted values and subtract 2 months
s = (df.groupby(['A','B'])['SortedDate'].shift().fillna(df['SortedDate']) - 
           pd.DateOffset(months=2))
#chain by bitwise AND (&) only for duplicated groups (lenghts 2 or more)
mask = df['SortedDate'].gt(s)  & df.duplicated(['A','B'], keep=False)
#set values by mask
df['Selected1'] = np.where(mask, 'Y', 'N')
print (df)
     A    B SortedDate Selected Selected1
0   aa  200 2020-01-01        Y         Y
1   aa  200 2019-12-23        Y         Y
2   aa  200 2019-10-24        N         Y
3   bb  400 2020-03-13        Y         Y
4   bb  400 2020-02-02        Y         Y
5   bb  500 2020-03-15        N         N
6   cc  700 2020-02-02        Y         Y
7   cc  700 2020-02-02        Y         Y
8   cc  900 2020-02-03        N         N
9   dd  900 2020-01-30        N         N
10  dd  200 2020-01-30        N         N
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael. It really solved my problem. Really thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask if row 2 (aa 200 2019-06-12), I change the date to 2019-10-24, will Selected1 become Y or N? Because based on the logic, the groupby will just take the first date which is 2020-01-01 and offset by 2 months ie 2019-11-01 which is later than 2019-10-24. By right it should be Y.

Comment: @BrianChew - My answer create `Y` for datetimes greater like first datetime - 2 months, so in first group all datetimes between `2020-01-01, 2019-11-01` are Y, else `N`. Do you need something else?

Comment: @BrianChew - Also this code is used only  for groups with length 2 or more, duplicated by `['A','B']` columns. So, rows 8,9,10 are always N, becauuse one element groups.

Comment: Yes, instead of comparing it to the first datetime, I need it to compare to previous row. Lets say I have a a group with length 3. OrderedDate are 2020-02-01, 2020-12-01 and 2020-11-01. I need all of them to be Y, Y, Y instead of Y, Y, N. Because 3rd date is within 2 months from 2nd date although more than 2 months from the 1st date.